# How to properly return and dispose of a dataset's dataview - seeing strange results

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, dispose, dataview

I'm trying to figure how to correctly return  a dataview. I noticed that if I bind to the resultant dataview used below, I don't get any results.

```
    private DataView filterDocuments(DataSet documents, string classType)
{
    using (documents)
    {
        //filter it
        using (DataView documentsByType = new DataView(documents.Tables[0], String.Format("ClassName = '{0}'", classType), String.Empty, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows))
        {
            return documentsByType;
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I don't dispose of my dataview, I can see teh results I want.  How can I properly return a dataview?

```
    private DataView filterDocuments(DataSet documents, string classType)
{
    using (documents)
    {
        //filter it
        return new DataView(documents.Tables[0], String.Format("ClassName = '{0}'",classType), String.Empty, DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
    }
}
```

Do I not need to dispose of it? Am I creating a memory leak? Do I have to pass the dataset by reference?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct place for the `using` (or calling `DataView.Dispose()` would be wherever you are making use of the `DataView`. It doesn't make sense to dispose of it in this spot.

Comment: I'm returning the value of the dataview - not a reference. So don't I need to dispose of the dataview in order to properly manage the application's memory?

Comment: I believe as soon as filterDocuments() is out of scope, the DataView you are returning within it would be set to be garbage collected. You're correct that it's by value, which is why you wrap it in a using wherever you are returning it to and making use of it.